# Idea unable import maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

my idea Unable to import Maven project,seems caused by openJDK ,but i dont sure

[image: IDEA maven configuration]

i use springInitalizr to init a simple spring demo
my computer profile as follows

- MacOS mojave 10.14.6
- AdaptOpenJDK with version 8.0.222.hs-adpt
- maven 3.6.2
- idea version is 2019.2.2

```
2019-09-08 20:23:08,571 [   9844]   INFO - tellij.diagnostic.LoadingPhase - Reached INDEXING_FINISHED loading phase 
2019-09-08 20:23:08,682 [   9955]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2019-09-08 20:23:08,838 [  10111]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.start create === 
2019-09-08 20:23:12,679 [  13952]   INFO - ings.impl.UpdateCheckerService - channel: release 
2019-09-08 20:23:15,246 [  16519]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.path.PathTranslator was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.model.path.PathTranslator
    for field at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.AbstractStringBasedModelInterpolator.pathTranslator(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$1.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:350)

2) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.path.UrlNormalizer was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.model.path.UrlNormalizer
    for field at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.AbstractStringBasedModelInterpolator.urlNormalizer(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$1.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:350)

2 errors 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.path.PathTranslator was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.model.path.PathTranslator
    for field at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.AbstractStringBasedModelInterpolator.pathTranslator(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$1.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:350)

2) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.path.UrlNormalizer was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.model.path.UrlNormalizer
    for field at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.AbstractStringBasedModelInterpolator.urlNormalizer(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$1.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:350)

2 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:159)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:344)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.customizeComponents(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:573)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.customize(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:542)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:209)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.customize(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:175)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$200(RemoteUtil.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:45)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:227)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:153)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.customize(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.doCustomize(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.onWrappeeCreated(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.doCustomize(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.lambda$customizeForResolve$1(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.customizeForResolve(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.resolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1261)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:140)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:33)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-09-08 20:23:15,247 [  16520]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2  Build #IU-192.6603.28 
2019-09-08 20:23:15,248 [  16521]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 11.0.3; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-09-08 20:23:15,248 [  16521]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-09-08 20:23:15,252 [  16525]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.ReimportProject
```

i hope someone could tell me how to fix it

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638826/creationexception-unable-to-create-injector-error-in-play-2-5-18-in-replacement

Answer (score 62):

It is known Maven 3.6.2 compatibility issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221882 .

A workaround is to change Maven version to 3.6.1 or older here:

[image: Maven version]

**UPD**: The issue has been fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it still didn't work after I changed the maven version to 3.5.4, I ended up replacing the Java version with Java HotSpot(TM) v1.8.0_171, it has be resolved.